# How to plot a graph of results from a for loop

Tags: python

I wish to simply plot the results of x and n and separately y and n for each n in the for loop and am getting stuck with the logic

```
import math
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 60

def Results():
    x = [0]*52 
    y = [0]*52
    n = [0]*52
    x[0] = Decimal(1)
    x[1] = Decimal(1)/Decimal(3)
    for i in range(1, 51):
        x[i+1] = (Decimal(13)/Decimal(3))*x[i] - (Decimal(4)/Decimal(3))*x[i-1]
        y[i]=3**(-(i+1))
        n[i]=i
        print(int(n[i]),float(x[i+1]),float(y[i]))
        
Results()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to plot it for every iteration as you're storing your values in an array. And you don't need `n` separately as indices of both `x` and `y` are same as `n`.
Simply do this:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 60

def Results():
    x = [0]*52 
    y = [0]*52
    n = [0]*52
    x[0] = Decimal(1)
    x[1] = Decimal(1)/Decimal(3)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
    for i in range(1, 51):
        x[i+1] = (Decimal(13)/Decimal(3))*x[i] - (Decimal(4)/Decimal(3))*x[i-1]
        y[i]=3**(-(i+1))
        n[i]=i
    ax[0].plot(x)
    ax[1].plot(y)
        
Results()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was confusing me for a while!